# Users created using new-mailbox script on exchange shell are disabled by default

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell, exchange-2013, user-accounts

I've done this many times before and I don't recall hitting this problem, however I'm creating mailboxes on exchange shell using new-mailbox and the accounts which are created in AD are all disabled by default.

I understand that this is normal behavour if a password is not supplied, however I've provided a password.

```
 New-Mailbox -Name 'Joe.Bloggs' -Alias 'Joe.Bloggs'  -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MyPassword123' -AsPlainText -Force) -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false -OrganizationalUnit 'MyDomain/MyTopLevelOU/ChildOU' -UserPrincipalName 'Joe.Bloggs@domain.com' -SamAccountName 'Joe.Bloggs' -FirstName 'Joe' -LastName 'Bloggs' -DisplayName 'Joe Bloggs'
```

Can anyone see why this would be the case or explain how I can resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This one was strange... The accounts are indeed disabled when created, however refreshing the AD users and computers screen 20 seconds later or so shows that they have been enabled.

I guess I was being too hasty.

Comment: It just need time to take effect. :)

Comment: This may also be a slight delay in your Active Directory Replication if they were created on one domain controller, and you were possibly viewing another.